# Global hotkey release (keyup)? (WIN32 API)

Tags: c++, winapi, hotkeys, registerhotkey

Is there a way to notice the release of a hot-key button registered with `RegisterHotKey`?

I get a `WM_HOTKEY` message every time I press the hot-key but I need to know when the key was released

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no specific notification for that specific action.  You will have to write a DLL that implements a global keyboard hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()`, then you will receive individual keypress up/down notifications and can match them up to your `WM_HOTKEY` notifications as needed.

Answer (score 6):

Use `RegisterHotkey` to detect the key going down, then use polling with `GetAsyncKeyState` until the key is no longer down. This avoids the complexity of `SetWindowsHookEx` and the polling is generally acceptable since it is only done while the hotkey is being held down.

Comment: IMHO the better solution if you only have one or a few hotkeys

Comment: Calling `GetKeyState` should also work and is preferred over `GetAsyncKeyState`.

Comment: @tigrou Why is it preferred?

Comment: calling `GetAsyncKeyState` too often can be detected by antivirus software as a keylogger.

Comment: Ah, people who use antivirus garbage deserve such things.